# JRebel doesn't publish webapp folder

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, web-applications, jrebel

I am trying to use JRebel and having problem while publishing the files like xhtml under src/main/webapp folder. I can do hot replacement of classes, it is working.

I am using Eclipse Helios, Tomcat 7 and JRebel Eclipse plug-in. Also i am using WTP.

I checked the tmp0\wtpwebapps\myapp-web directory. rebel.xml exists at WEB-INF/classes folder. So it should be ok.

Here is my rebel.xml

```
<classpath>
    <dir name="C:/Users/user/workspace/myapp/myapp-web/target/test-classes">
    </dir>
    <dir name="C:/Users/user/workspace/myapp/myapp-web/target/classes">
    </dir>
</classpath>

<web>
    <link target="/">
        <dir name="C:/Users/user/workspace/myapp/myapp-web/src/main/webapp">
        </dir>
    </link>
</web>
```

I tried a lot but could not understand why JRebel does not hot deploy webapp folder. I could not find anything useful at jrebel.log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remote the test-classes folder from rebel.xml classpath definition - you may have strage effects with that one.

When the application server starts, do you see JRebel: the directory 'blah' is being monitored" messages at the console?

Send the jrebel.log to support - they will help. It can be some minor version difference of the Tomcat instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It was a huge mistake to skip to add the licence key. I misunderstood that i will need the key 14 days later. and so i did not mind the licence warnings. sorry for inconvenience :)